# <a href="#id"> without it going to where said #id is

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/U6aKT/

```
<a href="#id">go to id</a>
<div style="margin-top:2000px;"></div>
<a id="id">id</a>
```

Based on the above example, is it possible for `<div id="id"></div>` to pop up without the page scrolling to where `<div id="id"></div>` is?

Comment: ... how would that work, considering the page *has to scroll* in order for #id to become visible?

Comment: as in, we ourselves have to scroll the page manually to see it without it automatically jumping to where #id is.

Comment: catch event in JS and do whatever you want to :)

Comment: i'm not familiar with JS, i'm sorry! haha

Comment: You have to use bootstrap modal. see my answer :)

Comment: Is your question how to "scroll there instead of jumping"? If yes, there's plenty of *scroll* plugins, scripts, ...

Comment: Hey, @Marox Tn what have you done. If not to be clicked then why have to put this <a href="#id">go to id</a> in html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your question and comment under diffrent answer you want to scroll down to #id div  or pop up the #id div when the link is clicked. If want to scroll then you have to use jquery animate function with scrollTop function; use the first way. And if you want pop up then use the second way.

### First way:

Here is the **[JsFiddel](http://jsfiddle.net/U6aKT/127/)**  with scroll animate

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<a href="#id">go to id</a>
<div style="margin-top:2000px;">TEST</div>
<a id="id">id</a>
<script type="text/javascript">$(document) .ready(function() {
  $('[href="#id"]').click(function() {
  $("html,body") .animate({scrollTop: $("#id").offset().top},1200, "easeOutBounce");
  return false;
  });
});</script>
```

### Second Way:

**Here is [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U6aKT/128/)**
You have to use bootstrap modal. You just need to initialize the the anchor tag   data-target attribute value as data-target="#id". And have to load the bootstrap css as well as jquery and bootstrap js. After that make your div   class="modal fade" id="id". And also add the modal content, header, footer. Enjoy!

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" > 

    <a href="#id"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#id">go to id</a> 

   <div class="modal fade" id="id" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="id" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
          Header
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body"> 
             Body
            <div class="modal-footer">
             Footer
            </div>
          </div> 
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src = "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" > </script>
```

Comment: sorry for the late reply, i was trying to understand the code you gave; i think it might just work, thank you! though, is it possible if say, the `<div id="id"></div>` won't appear as a pop up and instead appears below `<a href="id">id</a>` just like a normal text? i'm sorry if it sounds confusing, i'm just such a newbie.

Comment: Did you saw the  jssfiddle? or if you need just in below then I am cominng with new answer. :)

Comment: i don't have enough reputation, i'm sorry! hahaha

Comment: but, all's well. i'm pretty sure your answer is the best solution; thanks, ashik, and sorry for troubling you so much!

Comment: Actually he I think he was wanting a popup. Which he couldn't explain. Other wise he is wanting to copy the bottom div and append it to the first one. But  he was saying his requirement were fulfill (popup) with the modal :) . Some one has down-voted me. Please see the question nbefore editing.

Comment: Please see his comment before you came under my post. Also see his question before being editing. I don't know why are you insisting with me :( .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33330861/revisions   Also did you see the man who edited the question his reputation is 5. Then how much good he knows the requirement of anothe as a novice. And please visit his edited link I had gave..

Comment: Ok, If then I can also do :: his first requirement. But did you down-voted a answer with out completely revised the history. He told pop up

Comment: you have 26k + I am novice to you both in knowledge and ethics. The question was edited for 4 time.. :) from the main one..

Comment: originally, i was wondering how this website (http://saemyon.tumblr.com/symmetry/1) coded the information of its posts (the one beside the posts) to have it appear onclick. but your answer was okay too.

Comment: @배고파 now enjoy :) I have gave what you wanted both the scroll or the popup. See the both jsfiddel link

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is probably using javascript.

Assuming jQuery is already initialized:

```
$('[href="#id"]').click(function(e){ // bind clicking said link
    e.preventDefault(); // alternatively: e.stopPropagation();
});
```

You could also unbind and bind your click everytime, like so:

```
$('[href="#id"]').unbind('click').bind('click', function(e){ // bind clicking said link
    e.preventDefault(); // alternatively: e.stopPropagation();
    // EDIT:
    // I **strongly** recommend you use a class such as `fakeLink` 
    // or something since targeting every `href` is a pain in the... 
    // so your selector would then be $('.fakeLink') 
});
```

However, by default, it will look for an anchor by the `name` of `#id`, like so:

```
<a name="id"></a>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: i'm not exactly familiar with javascript, though i'll try to fiddle about with it. thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Since the `href="#id"` mechanism is all about scrolling, what I can recommend is to attach a JavaScript method to all `<A>` elements on page and play a bit with the DOM when `onClick`.

Comment: He is wanting a pop up. Please don't submit  answer without code.